# How do I get rid of XXX Auto-generated method stub

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc, auto-generate

I'm using an application called Eclipse to write java codes. So whenever I create a **"New Class"**, it creates this comment.

"XXX Auto-generated method stub"

This is starting to become very annoying for me to have to delete this every time I start coding and I just want to start coding from scratch on a blank page with no auto-comment and only have the public class and static void main.

```
public class LocalVars
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // XXX Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of this annoying random comment generator that does not apply to my coding?

I even went to `Windows` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Code Style` > `Formatter` > `Edit`

and then turn off all checkboxes in `Comments` and `Javadocs` as well. Still no help at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Code > Method body", click "Edit" and adjust to taste.

[image: Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Code > Method body]
[image: Code in created method stubs]

Comment: Hey thanks, that works! I deleted the comment and gave it a test run by creating a new class and it works!